# for (var key in object) - returning undefined - javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am sure I must have done something stupid, but I can't figure this one out.

Working in Google Apps Script, I have an object something like this:

```
{
  "advertiserId":"123456",
  "advertiserName":"Name",
  "advertiserVariables":{
    "U5":{
      "reportName":"transaction_date",
      "dataType":"STRING"
    },
    "U6":{
      "reportName":"Page_URL",
      "dataType":"STRING"
    },
    "U7":{
      "reportName":"Custom_1",
      "dataType":"STRING"
    },
    "U8":{
      "reportName":"Custom_2",
      "dataType":"STRING"
    },
    "U9":{
      "reportName":"Custom_3",
      "dataType":"STRING"
    },
    "U1":{
      "reportName":"pageType",
      "dataType":"NUMBER"
    },
    "U2":{
      "reportName":"productName",
      "dataType":"STRING"
    },
    "U3":{
      "reportName":"productId",
      "dataType":"NUMBER"
    },
    "U4":{
      "reportName":"productCategory",
      "dataType":"STRING"
    }
  },
  "audienceSets":{
    "4098242":{
      "tagName":"Name - Tag",
      "audienceSetName":"Visitors",
      "audienceGroups":{
        "productCategory":{
          "variableType":"U4",
          "audienceGroupName":"productCategory",
          "dataType":"STRING",
          "values":["category1","category2"],
          "uniqueValues":2,
          "active":true,
          "recency":30
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "shortAdvertiserName":"Name"
}
```

and in a function I want to loop over each `tagId` in `audienceSets`:

```
function buildRemarketingList(parameters) {

  initProfileId();

  Logger.log(parameters);

  for (var tagId in parameters.audienceSets) {

    Logger.log(tagId);
    Logger.log(parameters.audienceSets[tagId]);

  }
}
```

The first log action is returning the object as expected, with multiple objects within `audienceSets`. Logging the first value of `tag` also works as expected. However, I then get `undefined` for the line `parameters.audienceSets[tagId]` and the second loop doesn't work.

Since the values of `tagId` are being generated directly from the object, I don't understand how this can be going wrong?

Comment: I can't replicate it https://jsfiddle.net/bmv9zp9k/

Comment: I also had it working in plain JS ... is it possible this is specific to GAS?

Comment: is it possible you made a typo, because javascript is javascript

Comment: I too don't have any issues running this and cannot replicate your error.

Comment: In my environment, I couldn't reproduce your result using Google Apps Script, when ``parameters`` is given to ``buildRemarketingList(parameters)``. Can you show us the whole sample script that the error occurs? Of course, please remove your personal information from it.

Comment: I mean, I've learnt never to rule out typos, but I've checked this as thoroughly as I can and can't find any. I've copied this directly from my code - and stripped the code right back to just what is in the example above, and it still doesn't work. The `parameters` comes from all over the place so I'm not sure what value there is in showing exactly where it comes from - but I'll include the real object (as provided by the first log statement) if that helps.

Comment: Where you've logged the whole `parameters` object - does there happen to be a small blue `i` next to the object saying it's been re-evaluated when you expanded it? (Chrome does this, unsure of other browsers).  Are you perhaps logging and attempting to access the audience sets before they've been populated in an asynchronous manner, and by the time you expand the log out to view it, it's now populated?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I can't see one. The function does run asynchronously, but only after a user interaction, so the parameters object should be fixed...